# how to validate serialized data in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototypejs

I have this particular problem, where I need to validate the data before it is saved via an ajax call. `save_ass_rub` function is called when user navigates to a different URL.

In my application, I have a custom Window and user is allowed to input data. I am able to capture all the data in this step: `var data = $('form').serialize(true);`. But I need to loop through this and check if data for some specific elements is empty or not. I can't do it when the user is in the custom window. The Custom window is optional for the user. All I want is to **alert the user** in case he has left the elements blank before the data is submitted. 
We are using Prototype.js and ajax .

```
<script>
  function save_ass_rub() {
    var url = 'xxxx';
    var data = $('form').serialize(true);
    var result;
    new Ajax.Request( url, {
      method: 'post',
      parameters: data,
      asynchronous: false,  // suspends JS until request done

      onSuccess: function (response) {
        var responseText = response.responseText || '';
        if (responseText.length > 0) {
          result = eval('(' + responseText + ')');
        }
      }
    });
    if (result && result.success) {
      return;
    }
    else {
      var error = 'Your_changes_could_not_be_saved_period';
      if (window.opener) { // ie undocked
        //Show alert in the main window 
        window.opener.alert(error);
        return;
      }

      return error;
    }
  }

  // Set up auto save of rubric when window is closed
  Event.observe(window, 'unload', function() { 
    return save_ass_rub(); 
  });
</script>
```

Can some thing like this be done?

After Line 
`var data = $('form').serialize(true);
        var split_data = data.split("&");
        for (i = 0; i < split_data.length; i++) { 
            var elem = split_data[i];
            var split_elem = elem.split('=');
            if( split_elem[0].search(/key/) && split_elem[0] == '' ){
               console.log( split_elem );
               var error = 'Not all the elements are inputted';
               window.opener.alert(error);
               return;
            }
        }`

Comment: i recommend http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the serialized form string, I would use the form itself to do the validation. if `$('form')` is your form element then create a separate function that checks the form element so its compartmentalized.

```
function checkform(form)
{
    var emptytexts = form.down('input[type="text"]').filter(function(input){
        if(input.value.length == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
    if(emptytexts.length > 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and in the `save_ass_rub()` function

```
//..snip
if(checkform($('form') == false)
{
    var error = 'Not all the elements are inputted';
    window.opener.alert(error);
    return;
}
var data = $('form').serialize(true);
var result;
```

I only added text inputs in the `checkform()` function you can the rest of the input types and any other weird handling you would like to that function. As long as it returns false the error will be displayed and the js will stop otherwise it will continue